# This form should not contain extra fields createNamed Form null name and PUT method

Tags: forms, validation, symfony

I have an issue where when I create a named form with no form name as follows:

```
$this->get('form.factory')->createNamed(null, new UserFormType(), array());
```

where this UserFormType is defined to have a PUT method

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
    $builder->setMethod('PUT');
    $builder->add('firstname', 'text', array('label' => 'First Name'));
    $builder->add('lastname', 'text', array('label' => 'Last Name'));
    $builder->add('register', 'submit');
}
```

Then when I do a bind to the request I receive an error 'This form should not contain extra fields'.

```
if ($request->getMethod() == 'PUT') {
    //$form->bind($request);
    $form->handleRequest($request); // updated as per jperovic's comment
    if ($form->isValid()) {
        //...
    }
}
```

BUT when I remove the following line

```
$builder->setMethod('PUT');
```

and change the method check to POST

```
if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
```

It works just fine.

If I give a name to the form it also works.

```
$this->get('form.factory')->createNamed('user_form', new UserFormType(), array());
```

Any ideas to why PUT doesn't work with non-named forms?

**EDIT: Work around below**

Replace:

```
if ($request->getMethod() == 'PUT') {
    //$form->bind($request);
    $form->handleRequest($request); // updated as per jperovic's comment
    if ($form->isValid()) {
        //...
    }
}
```

With:

```
if ($request->getMethod() == 'PUT') {
    $request_data = $request->request->all();
    $children = $form->all();
    $intersect = array_intersect_key($request_data, $children);
    // Added token check for csrf protection
    if (array_key_exists('_token', $request_data)) {
        $intersect['_token'] = $request_data['_token'];
    }
    $form->submit($intersect);
    if ($form->isValid()) {
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: `bind`/`bindRequest` is quite an old way of submitting the form. Which version of Symfony do you have?

Comment: using 2.4.2, what's the newer way?

Comment: Ah, you should use `$form->handleRequest($request)` instead. `bind` (previously known as `submit`) was declared deprecated as of `3.0` version ;)

Comment: To elaborate a bit, as I'm aware (but I haven't used it yet), `bind` was supposed to be used with raw data (that is `array` or some class entity). If you wanted to pass the object of `Request` class (not raw data) you should have used `bindRequest` instead - and `bindRequest` has been deprecated in favor to `handleRequest` :)

Comment: Thanks for that, however the problem still remains even after using handleRequest